# Use of "save" or "save for" in sentences

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Take the following example sentence:

> There was nothing there save for the warmth of the immeasurable light.

Is this the proper use of **save for**?  Is there *ever* a proper use of **save for**?
Can someone explain to me the correct usage, if there is one, and possibly some etymology of this phrase?

Examples of other correct use would be appreciated, though not critical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definition of *save* in this example is [other than : but, except](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/save?show=2&t=1319942721).

[This article](http://eltj.oxfordjournals.org/content/XXXV/3/260.extract) gives a rather interesting discussion about when to use except/except for, and that applies equally to save/save for.

That article mentions one case where you would use the 'for' version:

> when what is excluded is different from what is included

Examples cited:

> Your essay is good except for the spelling.
>
> All the compositions are good except John's.

It goes on with several other cases, so I guess the nutshell answer is:  Both are correct in different situations, and the rules for figuring out which to use are fairly complex.

Comment: I think these examples are misleading. The reason you can use "except" in the second one and not "except for" is the word "all". Without the "all", you would have to say "The compositions are good except for John's".

Comment: That same page uses:  "*Everyone* was tired except for John" so I don't think it's the 'all' that makes the difference but some other subtle thing about the usage.

Comment: You can (and people usually do) use *except/save* instead of *except for/save for* after words like *everyone, all, nothing, no one, none* and nouns modified by adjectives like *all, whole, entire, every, no*. See [this webpage](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65522/lie-subgroups-of-su3).

Comment: I think maybe that's the wrong link?

Comment: Clearly. I meant to include [this one](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/except.htm).

Answer (score 5):

My first thought on reading this question was that although including the word "for" isn't exactly incorrect, it doesn't sit well with me. Here's the obligatory NGram showing I'm not alone...

[image]

The original meaning of [save](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=save) as *protect from harm* morphed through *preserve* -> *put aside* -> *make an exception of* -> *with the exception of*. This same meaning shift has also happened with the French [sauf](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/sauf%20%7B2%7D).

Comment: But going by Lynn's answer, the difference between "nothing save the" and "nothing save for the" is parallel to the difference between "nothing except the" and "nothing except for the", which would explain the ngram results: there's a wide difference in prevalence even though both are correct in different contexts. ([Link](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing+except+the%2Cnothing+except+for+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3))

Comment: I don't fully accept the implications of that link, in that I don't think there are strong "underlying rules" dictating when "for" can/should follow "save" or "except". But regardless of any such rules, the fact of the matter is we very rarely include the word "for" when the antecedent is "nothing". And that's the context we're talking about here.

Comment: Hmm... in "there was nothing there except for the warmth of the light", I would find it slightly odder to use "nothing there except the warmth of the light", because the warmth is not actually a "something" that's there. I feel that "except for" partly helps evade that issue. (And of course there are strong underlying rules at least in some cases: "The painting was good except one spot" or "Your essay is good except the spelling" are much improved by including a "for".)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: What can I say? Neither is "incorrect", but my NGram reflects nearly half a million usages *without* "for", against less than ten thousand *with* it. And I only looked into it in the first place because I thought OP's version wasn't the one I personally would opt for. But I agree with the link in Lynn's answer suggesting that we *do* tend to include "for" when the thing being excepted is a distinct sub-component of an antecedent "composite" noun (though not if it's just one element of a set of like items).

Comment: One of the rules for "except for" is that you use "except" and not "except for" after words like "nothing", "everything", "the whole house", etc. So after "nothing" you leave off the "for."

Comment: Not my mothertongue, but I dare to write something. Such a curve, as beautiful and worthy as it may seem, does not give an answer. Since it is clear that "save" is rare anyway, you compare something rare with something very rare. Put "except" and "except for" next to it and it and see that this is just a curve of trends. In English, so many words got replaced by Latin and Greek, and trends make these curves, not what is right or even best. Bring the English curve up again, drop the except, follow [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/46697/410036). :)

Answer (score 4):

"Save for" means "except for", a prepositional phrase.

1. In the story "The story of an hour" by Kate Chopin: "She knew that she would weep again when she saw the kind, tender hands folded in death; the face that had never looked **save** with love upon her, fixed and gray and dead."
2. The streets of Toronto were quiet this morning, save for a steady stream of cabs and cars weaving their way through the still dark streets.