# 'Come' as a subordinate conjunction

Tags: grammar

Is 'come' a subordinating conjunction in the following sentences?

'Come next February, he should have completed his degree.'

'He'll be wishing he'd arrived at Oslo come the winter.'

Comment: Looks like a verb. When next February comes. When winter comes. Or prepositionally - "at the arrival of."

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come) lists "1d2  to reach a condition or conclusion" with example "come to think of it" under *come* as a verb. But it still would be good to have an explanation as to why it's not in the simple present (is it a subjunctive?), and why you can't use other verbs in the same way (or can you?).

Comment: @StuartF In "Come rain, come shine" and "come hell or high water" it does look like a formulaic subjunctive. However, it may be a leftover from  *(when) winter is come.*

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456849/can-a-bare-infinitive-verb-as-the-first-word-of-a-sentence-form-a-clause).

Comment: No: this "come" is a **preposition** so "come next February" and "come the winter" are preposition phrases. Briefly, their function and internal structure are like that of a PP, compare "by nest Friday" / "By winter".

Comment: @KateBunting I'll let BillJ and tchrist duke it out, *come what may* :)

Answer (score 6):

> [*Come next February*], *he should have completed his degree*.

I would classify this "come" as a preposition.

Historically, this is a subjunctive clausal construction with "come" a plain form verb and "next February" its subject; synchronically, however, its function and internal structure are like that of a PP (compare "by next Friday"), and it is plausible to suggest that "come" has been reanalysed as a preposition.

The same applies to your other example.

Comment: Even though it's a dictionary, OL&G states this: *preposition*

1.
when a specified time is reached or event happens:
[informal]
"I don't think that they'll be far away from honors come the new season"

Comment: I agree with the grammatical parsing in this answer. To my mind, "Come next February" is very similar to the structure of "Enter bandaids" in the sentence "I wanted to come up with a way to patch open wounds. Enter bandaids!", in which it is used as a statement of something that happens/is introduced. The difference being that "Come [..]" is indicating a future event, and "Enter [..]" is _conversationally_ introduced at the present time.

Answer (score 2):

There is an assumption here that there is a valid answer to what is actually an interesting question.  The Cambridge English Dictionary gives an example of this type of expression:  "

> *informal* Come Monday morning [*= when it is Monday morning) you'll regret staying up all night)*].

There is no attempt to parse here.  It is treated purely as idiomatic.

Merriam Webster offers a different definition:

> to come to pass : take place —*used in the subjunctive with inverted subject and verb to express the particular time or occasion*

By way of example it offers: *Come spring the days will be longer.*

So Webster thinks of *come* in this context is a subjunctive. It does not offer a further explanation.

Collins English Dictionary offers a third perspective.  Under its explanation numbered 10, we find that it can be a preposition.

> You can use come before a date, time, or event to mean when that date, time, or event arrives. For example, you can say come the spring to mean 'when the spring arrives'.
> *Come the election on the 20th of May, we will have to decide.*
> *He's going to be up there again come Sunday.*

So according to Collins, *come* in this usage serves as a preposition.

Etymonline offers a useful perspective on the matter.

> elementary intransitive verb of motion, Old English cuman "to move with the purpose of reaching, or so as to reach, some point; **to arrive by movement or progression;**" also "move into view, appear, become perceptible;

*Come Spring* clearly refers to the arrival and in that sense is not the same is *in Spring*.  It has the advantage of brevity, by comparison with *at the start of Spring*.

But why, in that case are there no other such participial or subjunctive use, such as 'end winter'?  Well, language development is not necessary logical or consistent.  At some time *come* could have been used in this way, was understood and imitated.  The process of language development does not involve anyone thinking about existing grammar or semantics.  It is sufficient for such a locution to be immediately understood.  It can be called a colloquialism or, as Cambridge, *informal*.  Duke Ellington used the locution as the title of his wonderful composition *Come Sunday*.

Comment: [Oxford Learners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/come_2) labels *come* (preposition) as  *old-fashioned, informal*. However, it strikes me as a little old-fashioned/poetic and a bit formal, rather than informal.

Comment: I'll bet you anything you could find examples like *end winter* in Visser.

Comment: @tchrist:- I googled 'end winter here: [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/620724/come-as-a-subordinate-conjunction/620768?noredirect=1#comment1580042_620768].  As far as I can find there is no example.  the best I can find is "end of Winter" and "Winter's end".  I suppose a better analogy would be "go winter" or perhaps "leave winter".  But "go" and "leave" have no parallel use registered in Cambridge English dictionary.  But then perhaps people are more interested in the arrival of seasons than in their departure.

Comment: @Tuffy That is not what I meant. I meant obsolete constructions of the pattern "BARE-INFINITIVE NP" to represent the same thing as *Come the day* represents: "When the day should come" but with subjunctive inversion. You cannot find those with Googling because the spellings were different forms of English earlier than the present day under regular orthography. See Early Modern and Middle English.  Again, I bet Visser covers this, and I say this because I'm almost certain I've found it there before. But Google Books is no longer so generous with how much of Visser it lets you see.

Comment: @tchrist  Yes: the usage in the question can be thought of as a subjunctive.  The phrase 'come the day' has a modal, so subjunctive feel to it.  That is presumably why one of the dictionaries I cited treats "come" as a subjunctive.